# Set default input text in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

the code below is a text input in a plugins settings page. My question is how to set a default text like "Thanks for contacting us.".

```
  <input type="text" name="option_etc" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('option_etc') ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what you want to achieve, but you could try with this piece of code instead:

```
<input type="text" name="option_etc" value="<?php echo (get_option('option_etc') ? esc_attr( get_option('option_etc') ) : 'Thanks for contacting us.'); ?>
```

This will display the value of the setting if it exists, or your text if not. But be aware that nothing will be registered until the settings update-button is pressed. In other words; it will be like a placeholder and not have any effect front-end unless registered.

Comment: Perfect! It's exactly what i needed. Thanks!